# Add category and user name to recently updated post list

Tags: wp-query

I am using this code snippet to create a list of recently modified posts:

```
function wpb_lastupdated_posts() { 

// Query Arguments
$lastupdated_args = array(
     'orderby' => 'modified',
     'ignore_sticky_posts' => '1'
      );

//Loop to display 5 recently updated posts
    $lastupdated_loop = new WP_Query( $lastupdated_args );
    $counter = 1;
    echo '<ul>';
    while( $lastupdated_loop->have_posts() && $counter < 5 ) : $lastupdated_loop->the_post();
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $lastupdated_loop->post->ID ) . '"> ' .get_the_title( $lastupdated_loop->post->ID ) . '</a> ( '. get_the_modified_date() .') </li>';
        $counter++;
    endwhile; 
    echo '</ul>';
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
} 

//add a shortcode
add_shortcode('lastupdated-posts', 'wpb_lastupdated_posts');
```

The result is here:

http://newslines.org/recently-modified/

However, I would like to have the format:

Category - Post title - Author - Modified date.

I am not a programmer and my attempts to hack the code have not worked. Any help most appreciated!

Comment: Maybe start by formatting your code properly. It's unreadable in the current way.

Comment: I got the code from here: 

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-a-list-of-last-updated-posts-in-wordpress/

Comment: It doesn't really matter where you got the code from. It's unreadable. Please file an [edit] and reformat it.

Comment: Does that help? I am not a programmer so I am not sure of the appropriate format.

Comment: A bit, yes. I hope you're aware of the fact that this site is dedicated to _development_, so you'll have to be ready to read and understand code when you get an answer. There won't be anyone holding your hand and providing a copy/paste solution.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that. I can generally read code, but I find it difficult to write.